# How do I solve "Kotlin: Platform declaration clash:" on interface functions?

Tags: kotlin

Compiling this interface declaration I have the error

`Kotlin: Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (Function(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)V): fun Function(action: (Int) -> Unit): Unit defined in IInterface fun Function(action: (String) -> Unit): Unit defined in IInterface`

```
interface IInterface {
  fun Function(action: (Int) -> Unit)
  fun Function(action: (String) -> Unit)
}
```

But when I apply `@JvmName` attribute a have the error

`Kotlin: '@JvmName' annotation is not applicable to this declaration`

```
interface IInterface {
  @JvmName("Function1001")
  fun Function(action: (Int) -> Unit)
  fun Function(action: (String) -> Unit)
}
```

I've tried change interface to abstract class, but it doesn't help. Looks like `@JvmName` can be used only on class declaration.

What is the best practice to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `@JvmName` is disallowed in interfaces and open classes. The reason is explained in a comment to [KT-20068](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20068):

> @JvmName is problematic for overridable signatures, because then
> overriding in Kotlin and Java may start to disagree:
>
> ```
> interface A {
>   @get:JvmName("x")
>   val foo: Foo
> }
>
> interface B {
>   @get:JvmName("y")
>   val foo: Foo
> }
>
> class C: A, B {
>   // ???
>   override val foo = ...
> }
> ```

You can work around this limitation by adding

```
@Suppress("INAPPLICABLE_JVM_NAME")
```

but beware of the dangers.